# Google Fit location datatype yields 403 Permission Denied

Tags: google-fit

In my app I am requesting data from a Google Fit dataset using the "aggregate" function. This works fine for heart rate, speed, distance, etc., but this stopped working (but has been working before) for location data.

This is the request template I am using:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

{
 "aggregateBy": [
   {
     "dataTypeName": "com.google.location.sample"
   }
 ],
 "endTimeMillis": xxxx,
 "startTimeMillis": xxxx
}
```

For dataTypeName=="com.google.location.sample" the request returns:

```
403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "No permission to read data for this private data source."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "No permission to read data for this private data source."
 } 
}
```

Why is location data private? Has there been a change on the Google 
 API side?  Is there a different way to request location data?

These are the scopes my app is authorized for:

```
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read"
```

Note that the list includes "fitness.location.read".

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I found something in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/data-types):
"Exceptions
Whilst any application can write data to a public data type, there are certain data types which can only be read by the application that wrote the data."
Among those exceptions is com.google.location.sample. 

Is this restriction new or was it just not enforced before? How to access location data anyway? I feel there must be a way or the fitness.location.read authorization scope would be meaningless.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems), but I can't mark it as such until my answer there is upvoted or accepted. To address your question about what other types require the location scope: please refer to the table [on this page](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google fit permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems)

Answer (score -1):

I also try to get data from Google Fit but for "steps" and also sometimes getting the response with status 403

REQUEST:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];

$body = [
    "aggregateBy" => [
        [
            "dataTypeName" => "com.google.step_count.delta",
            "dataSourceId" => 
"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
        ],
        [
            "dataTypeName" => "com.google.distance.delta",
            "dataSourceId" => 
"derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_distance_delta"
        ]
    ],
    "bucketByTime" => ["durationMillis" => xxxx],
    "startTimeMillis" => xxxx,
    "endTimeMillis" => xxxx
];
```

RESPONSE:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "datasource not found (truncated...)

POST https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

DECISION:

All descriptions for error 403 you can see here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors

For resolving you can try to do this algorithm: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff
or your users should have sufficient permissions (403 "insufficientPermissions")