# How to get elevation data for a google fit session

Tags: google-fit

Since the latest changes to the Google Fit REST API, location data can only be read by the application initially wrote the data. See [Google fit permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems).

This is too bad since it allowed for useful features as tracking routes for workouts. But I can live without this.

However, what I really need for my data analysis is elevation data, i.e., track the elevation gain of the user during a workout session. Altitude gain is a rather important metric in the analysis of certain activities, often more important than distance.

My question is thus: Without the access to the location data (which included the user's altitude), how can I query elevation data from google fit for a given session?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: There's no direct call using Google fit API for the elevation. You can use `com.google.location.sample` to get the latitude, longitude, accuracy and altitude.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this approach is not possible anymore since Google restricted the access to location data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004208/10588509. So I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear that. There's still no update based from the documentation that's why I didn't know.