# Google fit elevation gain

Tags: rest, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-api

I'm creating a server-side app using the Google Fit REST API. One of the data points I want to retrieve is the elevation gain done by the user in a session. According to Google fits [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample) on location, where altitude is one of the data points, only apps that wrote to the platform can read the data.

I found this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537656/how-to-get-elevation-data-for-a-google-fit-session), unfortunately it has no solution. That's why I'm duplicating the question

My question is, how can I retrieve elevation data, for a session, without access to location data?

Comment: So what you are asking is how to workaround a google service contract? I don't think it is possible and probably unethical to use this service without paying for it.

Comment: Not really, distance is already available, and I only need the elevation gain done in an workout, not the exact location. I hoped there is a solution similar to distance for elevation gain.