# Accessing "com.google.location.sample" gives "No permission to read data for this private data source"

Tags: location, google-fit

The user is connected to GoogleFit sources using the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read". However when calling the GoogleFit API, I get status 403 with message `No permission to read data for this private data source`.
The request is -

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.location.sample:com.google.android.gms:merge_location_samples/datasets/1580313980000000000-1588098599000000000
```

I have found this post -  [Google fit permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems)
Is there any alternative to access the location using same scope?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google fit permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems)

Comment: "Is there any alternative" No, you are intentionally not able to read location data that you didn't write yourself.