# Getting "message": "No permission to read data for this private data source." for TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE and TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK

Tags: google-fit

can anyone please let me know how this issue can be solved, is this scope issue or something else.
URL : https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

````
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "No permission to read data for this private data source.", 
    "code": 403, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "forbidden", 
        "message": "No permission to read data for this private data source.", 
        "domain": "global"
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google fit permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618213/google-fit-permission-problems)

Answer (score -1):

You first need access to GPS, so you should add the permission to your `manifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fitness.sync">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
....
```

And in your code you should pass the permissions to the sign-in account as follows:

```
public void signIn(){
    FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            // add your read & write permissions here
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)

            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
             ...
            .build();

    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);

    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, // e.g. 1
                account,
                fitnessOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this currently on oauth playground where all permissions are given as well as I have used the given scopes, still I am facing same error